# jquery, datetimepicker, AM PM format отнимает время

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

У меня есть данный код

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var dt = new Date();
var minutes = dt.getMinutes();
var hours = dt.getHours();
var day = dt.getDate();
var workWeek = dt.getDate() + 7;

var month = '';
if (dt.getMonth() > 9) {
    month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
} else {
    month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    month = '0' + month;
}

var allowTimes = [];

if (minutes > 0 && minutes < 30) {
    allowTimes = ['09:30', '10:30', '11:30', '12:30', '13:30', '14:30', '15:30', '16:30'];
} else {
    allowTimes = ['09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00'];
}

jQuery('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    onSelectDate: function (date) {
        var selectedDay = date.getDate();
        if (selectedDay == day) {
            if (minutes > 0 && minutes < 30) {
                this.setOptions({
                    allowTimes: ['09:30', '10:30', '11:30', '12:30', '13:30', '14:30', '15:30', '16:30'],
                    minTime: hours + ":" + minutes
                });
            } else {
                this.setOptions({
                    allowTimes: ['09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00'],
                    minTime: hours + ":" + minutes
                });
            }
        } else {
            this.setOptions({
                allowTimes: ['09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00'],
                minTime: '09:00'
            });
        }
    },
    disabledWeekDays: [0, 6],
    minTime: hours + ":" + minutes,
    maxTime: '18:00',
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: dt.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + workWeek,
    allowTimes:allowTimes,
    format:'m/d/Y h:i a',
    formatTime:'h:i a',
    selectWeek: true,
});
});
```

Все работает отлично. Но почему то, когда я выбираю время, к примеру 02:00 PM, мне отнимает час и отображает 01:00PM, почему не могу понять. Как это исправить?

вот также пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719728/xdsoft-datetimepicker-plugin-am-pm-selection-fails, при выборе даты - отнимает один час

Comment: Часовой пояс пробовали указывать?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы время не отнималось, нужно использовать

```
validateOnBlur: false,
```